# Is it possible to use ActiveModel::Serializers outside of Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, active-model-serializers

I'm using `websocket-rails` gem for web-sockets and I would like to use ActiveModel::Serializers for creating JSON payload for web-socket message.
Is it possible to use serializer without using `render` in controller?

Comment: I can do it by explicetly instantating serializer: `ConversationSerializer.new(Conversation.last).as_json`

Comment: But I still can't figure out way to serialize a collection

Comment: oh got it: `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(Conversation.all, serializer: ConversationSerializer).as_json`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After looking into source code, I found answer I was looking for.
You can use AMS by explicitly instantiating serializer: `ConversationSerializer.new(Conversation.last).as_json`

for collection: 
`ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(Conversation.all, serializer: ConversationSerializer).as_json`

Comment: This class has been moved/renamed to: `ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer` in version 0.10.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Let's say that you have a `Product` model and a `p` record:

```
# p = Product.first
ProductSerializer.new(p).to_json
```

Also, be aware that you may have to load the required files:

```
require "action_controller"
require "action_controller/serialization"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/serializers/product_serializer.rb"
```

Comment: This only works if `p` represents a single instance of `Product` (e.g. `Product.first)`